# Dynamically update component prop value in array of components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

I have a list of `Image` components in my `App` component. In the `App` component, this list of `Image` components is passed to the `Display` component for rendering. Each `Image` component has a prop that is a function that deletes the component from the UI. When there is only one rendered `Image` left the in the `App`, I want to dynamically update its class. Currently, I can keep track of how many images are open in `App` with the useState variable `oneImg`. I'm trying to figure out how, when `oneImg === true` to update the className varaible `cName` in `App`.

// App.tsx

```
const [oneImg, setIsOneImg] = useState(false);
const [cname, setCname] = useState(() => {oneImg ? "singleImgClass" : "multiImgClass"}) // This doesn't seem to work
const images = [<Image key={0} className={cName} onRemove={remove()}/>, <Image key={1} className={cName} onRemove={remove()}/>]

<Display imgs={images} setIsOneImg={setIsOneImg}/>
```

// Display.tsx

```
function numberOfImages(imgs) {
    return cards.filter((img) => {
        return img.props.open;
    }).length;
}
const Display = ({ imgs, setIsOneImg }) => {
    setIsOneImg(numberOfImages(imgs) === 1);
    return (
        <div>
            {imgs}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Display;
```

How can `cName` be updated when `oneImg` goes from `false` to `true` or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cName is calculated from oneImg you don't have to store it as a state, App will be rerendered when oneImg is updated and you can just define cName as a const:

```js
const cName = oneImg ? "singleImgClass" : "multiImgClass";
```

should just work !